# How to make a self running file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, automation, websecurity

I have a activity in school about how a hacker might hack your pc without knowing, I was assigned to make a self running file, what I'm trying to do is, when a person for eg. Downloads a file, then without he opening it should already run without even the user opening it. Is this possible?

Comment: Ik it's a bad question, but I have to submit by day after tomorrow and couldn't find anything on google, so I asked on S.O :D

Comment: This is generally not possible, exactly because of the security problems.

Comment: That's why I asked, as there are many many self executing file that are made by hackers

Comment: Hackers take advantage of OS bugs that allow exploits. No one here is going to provide detailed instructions on how to hack the OS.

Comment: Oh lol okay then, I also dont want hacking instructions on S.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, not really actually.

If you want a file to be executed without the user executing it first after download, you will have to do one of such things:

1. Have an already running program on his machine that looks for your file and then executes it when he finds it in the downloads (MAGIC in the beginning of the file for example or hash validation).
2. Take advantage of a poorly protected software that executes other files or codes (Or override a standard library) file and make it run your code instead. of course this is not as simple as it sounds and requires you to understand the software that you are attacking pretty good.

   **Note:** Most programs won't just execute some arbitrary code and probably wont just use `execv` for no reason or without making sure that everything is correct and protected, which makes that solution (Without finding a security breach in the software) pretty difficult.

Comment: So are there any ways at all that a person downloads a file thinking it's a game or something, and without he opening it a hacker has access?

Comment: Or then how do hackers convince people to open a exe file at all?

Comment: @InfinitySquare Only if the attacker has achieved control over the victim's machine earlier (e.g. Taking advantage of a memory leak in other program that is being executed on the victim's machine or a vulnerability in the kernel). So to sum up - No, only if you find a vulnerability to exploit prior

Comment: Okay thanks!! I will research more on this

Comment: @InfinitySquare Good luck and don't join the bad guys ;)

Comment: I'm not a hacker, this is just a school assignment :P